# Setting HTML property with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a combination of JQuery, Modernizr, and Angular to achieve a custom Datepicker solution for a table generated via ng-repeat. The solution *works* if I hard-code the Angular directive of "datepicker" into the HTML.

So, for example, within my table using `ng-repeat"revenue in runway.revenues"` this works:

```
 <td> 
     <input type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="revenue.date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" datepicker required/> 
 </td>
```

But I would like for this to only be put into place when the user is in a browser that requires it. So, with this in mind, I have deleted `datepicker` from the above HTML, and written this in JS:

```
    $(function() {
        var nativeDateInputIsSupported = Modernizr.inputtypes.date;
        if (!nativeDateInputIsSupported) {
            $('input[type="date"]').prop("datepicker", true)
        }
    });
```

However, when I land on the page in Firefox, it does not appear to work.

Further, if I try to debug by doing something like `console.log($('input[type="date"]').prop("class"))` the value returned will be `undefined` (which should be `form-control`).

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure about the main problem because I have least experience in angular & modernizr, but the last one should be: `console.log($('input[type="date"]').attr("class"))` or `console.log($('input[type="date"]').prop("className"))`

Comment: Use `.attr()` to set attribute at HTML

Comment: @TaufikNurRahmanda, I tried those too and neither worked (still returns undefined). And for the guest friend, that does not work. I have done .attr("datepicker", "") which does nothing. Also, as of September, that doesn't seem to work with JQuery according to a few other Stack Overflow users.

Comment: @AlexGelinas I suspect the problem is because of conflict between libraries (jquery+angular+modernizr), is there any console error message? if no, try `console.log($('input[type="date"]').length)` (it will get the number of matched element exist in DOM, if there's more than 1, `.attr()` or `.prop()` won't work), if result is 1, then try `console.log($('input[type="date"]').prop('outerHTML'))` (maybe really there's no class attribute)

Comment: Hm, if I try `console.log($('input[type="date"]').length)`, the returned result is 0. This occurs if I include it within a `$(document).ready(...` as well

Comment: @AlexGelinas that's unexpected, of course the `attr` and `prop` result is undefined because there's no matched element selected. try Ctrl+U > Ctrl+F > type 'type="date"'. If there's match and the tag name is `<input>`, it is unbelievable.

Comment: If I inspect the element, I can see type="date" for sure.

Comment: I have answered it below! Thank you for your help =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by taking an idea from user @guest271314 and expanding on it a bit!

Rather than adding the attribute to the HTML based on Modernizr, I set a $scope variable equal to a boolean value.

```
  $(function() {
        var nativeDateInputIsSupported = Modernizr.inputtypes.date;
        if (!nativeDateInputIsSupported) {
            $scope.datePickerValue = "true"
        }
    });
```

Within my directive, I added this:

```
function link(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
        var requiredParam = attrs.datepicker === 'true'; //This was what was added
        if (requiredParam) { //Checking for boolean value
            element.datepicker({
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                maxDate: '0'
            });
        }
    }
```

Which meant that in my HTML I added `datepicker="{{datePickerValue}}"` to the Date inputs, which now works!! Thank you for all of the help, I wouldn't have come back to this without your input =)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.attr()` or `.setAttribute()` to set attribute at HTML

```js
document.querySelector("input").setAttribute("datepicker", true);

console.log(document.querySelector("input").outerHTML);
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

```js
$("input").attr("datepicker", true);

console.log($("input")[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="text">
```

```js
$("input").prop("datepicker", true);

console.log($("input")[0].outerHTML); // attribute not set at HTML
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="text">
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me. Please bear in mind there are 7 different inputs on this table (I only included the date for brevity), hence why I was using `'input[type="date"]'`. Also, it should not be `datepicker="true"` in the HTML, it should simply be `datepicker` (like in the HTML example at the top, or if you were to use `required` for an input). That's why I was using `prop('datepicker',true)`.

Comment: @AlexGelinas Can you describe "didn't seem to work"? Whether one or more `<input>` elements the same result should occur, where correct selector is used. Why is only `datepicker` attribute at HTML without a value the expected result?

Comment: "Didn't seem to work" as in had no effect. The `datepicker` attribute is a directive I created in Angular, as mentioned in the initial question =) I had given an example of what worked with the top block of HTML code.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is possibly to do with the fact that the section of HTML I am referring to doesn't technically exist in the DOM. It is what is being used to generate the table with ng-repeat. But if I try to do the same thing(s) after a `$(document).ready(...` it is still not effective.

Comment: _"it should simply be datepicker"_ At which browser did you try setting `datepicker` attribute without a value and the HTML rendered `<input datepicker>` and not `<input datepicker="">`?

Comment: I came to an answer which can be seen below. It was thanks your point of "why not having the `datepicker` attribute equal to something."